# When will we be able to use a custom corpus?

Tags: ibm-watson

When will ibm make it's Watson Q&A api capable of accepting a custom corpus? 
Is there a roadmap I can see?

Comment: does @Jeff Sloyer have an answer? :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not about prognosticating vendor activities.

Comment: fair enough I was just looking for an answer from @jeff-sloyer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is addressed to a particular user asking about scheduling of features.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [Question and Answer](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/question-answer.html) service currently doesn't provide a way to use your own data. You can get **similar or better** results by combining [Document Conversion](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/document-conversion.html) and [Retrieve and Rank](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html).

You will use Document Conversion to convert your corpus documents (PDF, docx, html) to answer units that will be indexed by the Retrieve and Rank service.

The Retrieve and Rank service is built on top of Apache Solr, and once you load your data into the Solr index, you can create and train a Ranker (machine learning model that knows how to sort results).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on German's answer, also take a look at the Watson [Natural Language Classifier](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/nl-classifier.html) (NLC) and [Dialog](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/dialog.html) services, which are additional building blocks for creating a custom Question and Answer application. NLC classifies text and allows you to trigger an action, and Dialog allows you to create and manage virtual conversations with your users.

[Here is a great blog](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2015/09/28/combining-natural-language-classifier-and-dialog-to-create-engaging-applications-2/) with an introduction to both NLC and Dialog. And [another good blog](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/blog/2015/10/05/retrieve-and-rank-finds-highly-relevant-content-buried-deep-in-complex-information/) that introduces the Watson Document Conversion and Retrieve and Rank services.